# How to Forcefully Rollback a Setup from Custom Actions?

Tags: .net, installation, setup-project

I am creating a installer in .NET and using custom actions for controlling installation. Now there is certain conditions which I need to check and based on those I have to continue install OR rollback the installation.

How can I forcefully rollback the Setup from custom actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two resources (which will answer your question):

- http://community.installshield.com/showthread.php?t=141844
- http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/