# How to rollback uninstallation in custom action?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I am displaying a `MessageBox` in `OnBeforeUninstall` override in custom installer class.

I have assigned the installer class to `Uninstall` in Custom Action Editor of Visual studio setup project.

Now based on dialog result, I need to rollback the uninstallation?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207823/how-to-forcefully-rollback-a-setup-from-custom-actions) but these are specific to Installshield. I need to do it in Visual Studio setup project.

I have tried `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` but it puts the installation in unstable state.

I have also tried [`this.Rollback()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.rollback.aspx) but it shows following error

> Error 1001. An exception occured while uninstalling. This exception will be ignored and the uninstall will continue. However, the application might not be fully uninstalled after the uninstall is complete. -> The savedState parameter cannot be null."

Answer (score 0):

If the Messagebox in the Installer project is in shown during the 
[Install](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx) override. Then if you

```
throw new InstallException();
```

The Rollback override will execute.

{MyInstallerProject} > RightClick > Add Project Output > Choose Project from Drop Down > Choose Primary Output > OK. View | CustomActions > Right Click Install > Add Custom Action > Double Click Application Folder > Choose 'primary output from {CustomActionprojectname} (Active)'

Repeat but for "Rollback" instead of "Install" in above instructions.